# The behaviour of bind Service, MP still playing multiple files

Tags: android, service, bind

I have a service bound to an activity. The activity is a `ListView` of playable files. The service plays a certain audio file, passed from the `Activty`. In the previous version I hadn't had the Service bind, so when clicking multiple times on a play element, multiple instances of sounds would occur. I thought I could solve this by binding the service, so I would communicate every time with the same instance, however it still plays multiple files if they are clicked. Maybe i understood the concept of binding wrong, I'm not sure, the android documentation is sometimes a bit vague and misleading. Here is my code, thanks for any input.

Activity:

```
public class ViewSounds extends ListActivity {

  private PlayService myService;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

  // Bind Service
  Intent intent = new Intent(ViewSounds.this, PlayService.class);       
  getApplicationContext().bindService(intent, serviceConncetion, BIND_AUTO_CREATE); 

  // Get list vars
  String[] lex_names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lex_names);
  //final String[] lex_files = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lex_files);

  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_sounds, lex_names));  
  final ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {                   

    //int playFile = getResources().getIdentifier(lex_files[position], "raw", getPackageName());   
     myService.playAudio();

    }
  });   
  }  

  private ServiceConnection serviceConncetion = new ServiceConnection() { 

   @Override
   public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) { 
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
         myService = ((PlayService.MyBinder)service).getService();                   
         } 

         @Override
         public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
         myService = null; 
         } 
        }; 

         @Override
         public void onDestroy(){ 
         super.onDestroy(); 
         unbindService(serviceConncetion);    
         }
 }
```

Service:

```
public class PlayService extends Service {

MediaPlayer player;

private final IBinder binder = new MyBinder();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return binder;
}       

public class MyBinder extends Binder {
     PlayService getService() {
        return PlayService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

public void playAudio(){   
            // I hardcoded the file name for this preview

    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.no_harm);
    player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
    if (!player.isPlaying()) {      
    player.start(); 
    }
 }

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Service created ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Get veriable from Activity
    // int extras; 
    // extras = intent.getExtras().getInt("playFile");          

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stop playback of previous file before playing another file. In your code you actually creating new `MediaPlayer` for each new media file.

Here is how your `playAudio` should look like:

```
public void playAudio(){   
   // I hardcoded the file name for this preview

   if(player != null){
       player.release();
   }

   player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.no_harm);
   player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
   if (!player.isPlaying()) {      
      player.start(); 
   }
}
```

But you should avoid creation of new media players for each new playback. You could do this next way:

```
public void playAudio(){   
   // I hardcoded the file name for this preview

   if(player == null){
        player = new MediaPlayer();
   }

   if(player.isPlaying()){  
        player.stop();
   }

   player.reset();
   player.setLooping(false);

   player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){
        @Override
        void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp){
            mp.play();
        }
   });       
   player.prepareAsync(); 
}
```

You should also use `onSetErrorListener(...)` and `onSetComlpletionListener(...)` for more control over the player. So that your activity can react on state changes in `MediaPlayer`.